# How to obfuscate dll generated by xsltc

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xslt, obfuscation

I need to maintain an xslt code that has 10s of thousands of lines.
It was developed a long time ago and it is integrated to a visual studio console application by running xsltc as a pre build event that creates a dll and that dll is finally referenced by the visual studio project.

In order to sell the final executable, I need to obfuscate the whole solution.
The tool I have been using to obfuscate works correctly for all executables and dlls files created by visual studio, but if I obfuscate my xslt dll, then my code throws a runtime error saying that it cannot find my xslt dll.

I would like to know, if you have already worked on projects using xslt dlls, how did you manage to maintain a secure version of these dlls?

Comment: obfuscated != secure

Comment: I agree with you. Do you have any suggestion about how to work on this issue?

Comment: It's hard to give concrete suggestions without a lot of the information about the scenario, tooling, etc., but the likely cause is that your code is trying to load the XSLT DLL or a type within it, and the obfuscation is renaming that DLL or type. The obfuscation tooling should have a way to exclude code elements from renaming. (In the interest of disclosure, I work at a company that creates such a tool, but this advice should be applicable to other tools as well.)

Answer (score 0):

I have deleted the pre-build event that ran xsltc and used the input stylesheet as an embedded resource that is not copied to the output directory.
As the stylesheet is not copied to the output directory anymore, I changed the loading code a bit:

```
XsltSettings settings = new XsltSettings(true, true);
Stream stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("namespace.stylesheetname.xslt");
XmlReader embeddedReader = XmlReader.Create(stream);
XslCompiledTransform xslt = new XslCompiledTransform();
xslt.Load(embeddedReader, settings, new XmlUrlResolver());
```

Now I have a single executable file that I could finally obfuscate.
If you intend to use the code above, double check that you are closing the files you have opened.